# distributing differnet elements horizontally inside a div with CSS

Tags: html, css

**Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gq8s4/)**

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="Trigger">click here</div>

<div id="TheContainer">
    <div class="One">this is some text</div>
    <input type="button" class="Two" value="button 1" />
    <input type="button" class="Three" value="button 2" />
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#TheContainer{
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px 30px;  
    display:none;
    background:red;}

.One{float:left;}
.Two{float:left;}
.Three{float:left;}
```

I use the following javascript to show/hide the container:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.Trigger').click(function () {

        var TheContainer = $('#TheContainer');

        if (TheContainer.is(':visible') === false) {
            TheContainer.show();  
        } else {
            TheContainer.hide();
        }       
    });
});
```

As you can see, we have a container of fixed width that's hidden, and that contains 3 elements: 1 div and 2 buttons, all 3 of variable sizes because the text of these elements changes at runtime.

I'm looking to horizontally distribute the 3 children elements evenly inside the container. I've looked around and for various reasons, none of the existing solutions seem to work for this particular case.

How can I distribute these elements horizontally and evenly using just CSS?
*Note: I know I can do it in jQuery by calculating widths and then setting positions absolutely but I'm looking to see if there's a CSS only solution.*

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/gq8s4/5/

It involves creating a div around each button so the buttons themselves are not really wide.

```
<div id="button1"><input type="button" class="Two" value="button 1" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Adjusted answer to new details.

http://jsfiddle.net/gq8s4/3/

```
.triple-container {
    float: left;
    width: 33.333333%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.One{
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.Two{
    width: 20px;  
}

.Three{
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I'm looking for: the buttons aren't supposed to be that wide, just evenly distributed.

Comment: OH.  How about this then... (see edit in a few short minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is about as close as you're going to get.

http://tinker.io/eb980

```
#TheContainer {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%; /* for old Firefox */
}
```

Support:  Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE10.  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

If you're comfortable adding extra markup, you could fake this with `display: table-cell` but it won't be perfect:

http://tinker.io/eb980/2

```
#TheContainer {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
}

div:last-child {
    text-align: right;
}

<div id="TheContainer">
    <div class="One">this is some text</div>
    <div><input type="button" class="Two" value="button 1" /></div>
    <div><input type="button" class="Three" value="button 2" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: At the minimum, I need IE8 support so that option doesn't work either. Besides, it also resizes the container, which is not what it's supposed to do: it's 500px wide and doesn't resize.

Comment: You can achieve what he wants without flexbox.

Comment: @Michael not really.  You can get close, but it won't be perfect.  Modify the contents of any of the elements and you'll see that only Flexbox handles it gracefully.

Comment: @frenchie I missed the width you specified and gave it a generic width (a width other than auto is necessary for Firefox).  You can see it with a 500px wide container here:  http://tinker.io/eb980/3.  I've added an alternate solution as well.